# とした in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Here's the sentence :

> 僕とした事が忘れてたよ。

What is the role of とした ?

Comment: Thank you, it is helpful. How would you translate my sentence, then ? "Even I, (of all people), have forgotten" ?

Comment: ^^^^^ maybe could be a good new question, but we don't do free translation work.